# Preventing Bootstrap Sticky Footer From Allowing Content To Slide Beneath

Tags: html, css

I've got a sticky bootstrap footer at the bottom of my page, however when I scroll down the content is hidden below it, and you cannot see a full image for example.
[image]
Above is a screenshot of the footer itself, it's 300px high and allows the content to slip 300px under it, which means when there is a vertical overflow and scrolling is required, 300px of imagery/content is hidden below the sticky footer. As seen below:
[image]
Whereas the actual image is this, you can see compared to the above image that it's not cut off:
[image]
The only solution I can think of is to set the boarder for any other content to be 300px from the bottom, but how would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some padding-bottom to the content. 
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem. Putting a padding at the bottom of half the width of the sticky footer (150px in my case) will fix this issue if you have an overflow (Scroll) at the bottom with lots of content. This ensures that the content is stopped before it hits the top of the footer.

To do that, I just created a div and applied that style to it:

```
<div id="pagecontent" style="padding-bottom: 150px;">
    <!--Content Goes Here-->
</div>
```

Much thanks goes to Pragyakar Joshi for suggesting the padding to the content!